# Using valence to put attendance data into desire2learn

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am just starting to use Valence and have been asked to put attendance data into the attendance tool from a csv file created by a swipe device. Has anyone done this before?

Chuck

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the lengthy delay in response. I'm sorry, but the Attendance tool available in Brightspace does not currently offer any APIs in the Valence Learning Framework developer platform.

In future, I would suggest that you visit the [forums at D2L's developer community site](https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/support) for more timely access to their dev platform support.